# pandas dataframe to vertica table insertion faster way

Tags: python, pandas, vertica

I have code like this..it's working fine but its taking too much time to load the data into vertica. around 10 mins for 1000 rows. is there any alternative/faster way to insert the data in vertica.

```
import pandas as pd
import vertica_python

conn_info = {'host': '127.0.0.1',
         'user': 'some_user',
         'password': 'some_password',
         'database': 'a_database'}

connection = vertica_python.connect(**conn_info)

df = pd.DataFrame({'User':['101','101','101','102','102','101','101','102','102','102'],'Country':['India','Japan','India','Brazil','Japan','UK','Austria','Japan','Singapore','UK']})

lists= df.values.tolist()

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    for x in lists:
        cursor.execute("insert into test values (%s,%s)" , x)
        connection.commit()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use in `cursor.copy` option instead of `cursor.execute`.

For example:

```
# add new import:
import cStringIO
...
# temporary buffer
buff = cStringIO.StringIO()

# convert data frame to csv type
for row in df.values.tolist():
    buff.write('{}|{}\n'.format(*row))

# now insert data
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.copy('COPY test (Country, "User") FROM STDIN COMMIT' , buff.getvalue())
```

On my testing system following results

your implementation:

```
$ time ./so.py
real    0m4.175s
user    0m0.523s
sys 0m0.101s
```

my implementation:

```
$ time ./so.py
real    0m0.814s
user    0m0.530s
sys 0m0.078s
```

5 times faster(4.175s vs 0.814s).

Comment: @sKwa..Thanks it worked very well. i am inserting the data user wise i don't know why after some users data not loaded. do you know why?

Comment: @KumarAK, I can't answer, not enough details.

Comment: Regarding this question.... df.to_sql() won't work with Vertica?? Thanks